# Cannot fit background image fully

Tags: coronasdk

So I am trying to fit my 350x570 image file fully as a background. But it's not working no matter what I do. Here's my code:

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

local background = display.newImageRect("background.png", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY
```

and here's what I get:

[image: preview]

As shown in the image, there are two black bars because it's not fitted properly. But I don't know why. The code seems ok so what's the problem?

Comment: Read more about [Content Scaling](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html#contentscaling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal coordinate system of Corona SDK depends on the content area defined in config.lua file. Point (0,0) is positioned at the top-left corner of this content area. If you are using the default Config.lua file then point (0,0) may not be positioned on the top-left corner of the screen.

Tutorial on modernizing the config.lua

https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/10/modernizing-the-config-lua/

Ultimate Config.lua file

https://gist.github.com/pkoperek/11156473

Comment: Thanks! I just had to change from `"letterbox"` to `"zoomStretch"`